# Table name as parameter for Microsoft SQL Server procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to use a SQL Server procedure to create two tables with different names depending on whether a variable is yes (1) or no (0). Everything I've seen refers to temporary tables. I would like to store the table permanently in the database.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DUALTYPE 
    @TableName nvarchar(18), @YesNo int 
AS 
BEGIN 
    SELECT * 
    INTO dbo.[@TableName] 
    FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM mytable
         WHERE dual = @YesNo) dualtab
END

EXEC DUALTYPE @TableName = 'dualtable' @YesNo = 0
```

The procedure executes, but it thinks my table name is @TableName. How do I tell it to use 'dualtable' instead?

Comment: *to create two tables with different names depending on whether a variable is yes (1) or no (0)* - you don't appear to be doing this at all, you're trying to pass the table name explicitely and using `@YesNo` to filter which rows are being populated.

Comment: You'll need, at a bare minimum, a CREATE TABLE statement. Are you sure this is what you want to do though? Like what are you trying to solve for? The requirement sounds a little fishy.

Comment: Ok. I am using Microsoft SQL; I thought that CREATE TABLE was only for Oracle.

Comment: You can't use a parameter as an object name. If you want to pass an object name you must construct a sql statement as a string to be executed with [`EXECUTE sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

Comment: *I thought that CREATE TABLE was only for Oracle* how did you come to that conclusion? `create table` is ISO SQL used by almost every DBMS - maybe the Oracle reference is where *dual*  originates from also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below, using T-SQL, allows for different variable inputs using the same query. The output is then stored in different tables on the database. It is good for making unique samples based on different variable criteria.

The declare statements establish the variable type inputs. Those inputs are then defined using the set statements. 'Set @query' is a string which contains the relevant query (in this case, creating a table based on whether 'dual' is yes vs. no). Because the alterable parameters are contained in a string, they are defined using set @parm N'@...', and then connected to the actual variables in 'EXEC...@parms...'. The query below will produce a table named 'Yes' or 'No' if the YesNo variable is set to 1 or 0, respectively.

```
declare @TableName sysname;
declare @YesNo int;
declare @parms nvarchar(max);
declare @query nvarchar(max);

set @TableName = 'Yes'
set @YesNo = 1
set @query = '
    Select * into [mydb].dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '
    from 
    mytab
    where dual = @lvl'
set @parms = N'@lvl int'

EXEC sp_executesql @query, @parms, @lvl = @YesNo
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?